# Issue in installing Mcrypt extension in mac OS 10.13

Tags: macos, mcrypt

I am trying to run codeigniter project on mac but it is showing **"The Encrypt library requires the Mcrypt extension."** error.I have tried many solutions to install Mcrypt extension but every time i am getting errors.I have tried to install it using homebrew using **brew install php5-mcrypt** command but getting **No available formula with the name "php5-mcrypt"**  error everytime.Issue is i am new to mac so now I am stuck because i don't know how to solve this issue. Can anyone help me and give me guidance that exactly what should i do to install Mcrypt extension? I am using PHP version 7.2.4 and macOS 10.13: High Sierra (Lobo).

Comment: Please provide all details of what you're trying to do, keep in mind, we're not oracles.

Comment: It is best not to use PHP mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated was removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete  Now you can check my question again. Sorry I was in a hurry so forgot to write some info. And thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you try MacPorts. It's like Homebrew but I've had better luck recently. There is a port for php72-mcrypt if that's the one you are after.  There are many others available as well. The MacPorts home page, [found here](https://www.macports.org/index.php) gives instructions for loading MacPorts and also has a list of available ports.

Answer (score 0):

`mcrypt` has been removed from PHP core since 7.2. To install `mcrypt` in PHP 7.2, you have to install via PCEL. The command is:

```
sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
```

You might want to read the [official installation documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php) as well.

Answer (score 0):

For mac users install MAMP pro and select a php version that has mcrypt. 
That is to say any version before php 7.2 .
Start the servers and voila you’re good to go.